# Terminal is unresponsive after running npm create vite

Tags: npm, terminal, create-react-app, vite, command-prompt

After running `npm create vite` the terminal is unresponsive, here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of unresponsive terminal]

Also when choosing `React/javaScript` I don't see the arrows.

What can be the problem? I want to see the command prompt after vite finished.