# How to get back to the terminal prompt?

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line, operating-system, vite

After certain operations using vite :
like after running the npm run dev command , in my terminal , I am not able to see my terminal prompt.
How should I return back to it ?

I tried ctrl + q , ctrl + z and it didn't work.
Are there any other ways ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77893936/terminal-is-unresponsive-after-running-npm-create-vite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing Ctrl + C to interrupt the current process and return to the terminal prompt.

Comment: Looks like it is stuck, see suggested duplicate.